# Cmake: Specify custom path to STL library (libstdc++)

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

Having compiled a new version of `gcc` I've also compiled standard c++ library that came with it.

I specify to `cmake` using new compiler by exporting `CC` and `CXX` variables like `export CXX=/path/to/gcc-13.2/bin/g++`

But instead linking fresh-compiler's STL, `cmake` links system-wide STL.

I have tried to set

```
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_IGNORE_PATH=/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/gcc-13.2/lib -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH=/path/to/gcc-13.2/include
```

But it does not work, `ldd executable` shows:

```
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f50f5d3f000)
```

and in runtime I get:

```
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.32' not found (required by ....)
```

How do I specify to `cmake` to use new compiler's includes and libs?

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Cross%20Compiling%20With%20CMake.html

Comment: Isn't this a generic dynamic linking issue? You should use the usual tricks to point the dynamic linker to your custom libstdc++ (LD_LIBRARY_PATH, RPATH, ...)